# Как сериализировать textarea?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

При сериализации textarea, PHP выдает Undefined index. Как получить данные на сервере?

*HTML:*

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><textarea name="text1"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea name="text2"></textarea></td>
        <td><button>button</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "1.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $("#res").text(response);
        }
    })
});
```

*PHP:*

```
    echo $_POST['text1']; // выводит Undefined index:
    echo $_POST['text2']; // Undefined index
```

Comment: @vasily_dumov посмотрите [документацию по `.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) – там есть пример.

Answer (score 2):

У вас сейчас сериализация кнопки происходит. Нужно добавить `form` и у него `serialize` спрашивать.

```
<form action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><textarea name="text1"></textarea></td>
            <td><textarea name="text2"></textarea></td>
            <td><button>button</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
$(document).on("click","button",function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"1.php",
        type:"post",
        data:$(this).closest('form').serialize(),
        success:function(response){
            $("#res").text(response);
        }
    });
});
echo $_POST['text1'];//выводит Undefined index:
echo $_POST['text2'];//Undefined index
```

Comment: ,да нет же,добавлять form не обязательно

Comment: `$(document).on("click","button",function(){ console.log($(this).serialize()) });` что будет? у вас `this` = `button` о какой сериализации речь то идет?  да, `form` необязательно, но селектором должно быть `input, textarea, select`

Comment: добавил 
    <code>$(document).on("click","button",function(){
 val=$(this).parent('td').siblings('td').find('textarea').serialize();
 console.log(val); 
  $.ajax({
   url:"1.php",
   type:"post",
      data:{val:val},
   success:function(response){
    //console.log($(this).val());
    console.log(response);
    $("#res").text(response);
   }
  }) 
      })</code>
но результат тотже,что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Ну явно не так, как вы сделали. Во-первых, зачем вам сериализация?

```js
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "1.php",
    type: "post",
    data: ({
      text1: $("#text1").val(),
      text2: $("#text2").val()
    }),
    success: function(response) {
      $("#res").text("ok" + response);
    }
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <textarea id="text1"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <textarea id="text2"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>button</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: хочу сделать именно с сериализацией, $("text1").val() не совсем мне подходит т.к. строк в таблице у меня будет множество

Comment: А при сериализации они у вас не уменьшатся. Во-вторых, вы сериализуете целый документ а не поля ввода. В  третьих вы где собрались проводить десериализацию? В ПХП ? А вас не смущает сериализация средстави javascript ?

Comment: Я сеарелизую именно поля ввода,собсвтвенно когда нажимаю на кнопку.а зачем мне десериализация?я передаю на сервер данные где тупо вывожу их.Можете  помочь с сеарилизацией?

Comment: и да @ArchDemon заменил свою строчку на вашу,ошибки выводит теже

Comment: Вам не нужна сериализация. Вам нужно сделать так, как я написал в своём ответе

Comment: ,здесь  я использую сериализацию исключительно для примера (да тут она особо и не нужна),но я повторюсь запускаю исключительно ваш код и у меня ничего не работает(Undefined index: text1 и Undefined index: text2)

Comment: Он и будет это писать, если вы пытаетесь прочитать данные не отправив их. Или читать данные там, куда они не приходят и приходить не должны. Выучите наконец-то функцию var_dump(), пользы уйма

Answer (score 0):

JS должен быть примерно такой:

```
$('button').on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "1.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $("textarea").serialize(), // <-------
        success: function(response) {
            $("#res").text(response);
        }
    })
});
```

[**Рабочий пример**](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/m9kLm6nq/).

Comment: ,ответ тот же Undefined index

Comment: Рабочий пример смотрели? Ещё откройте консоль разработчика в браузере и посмотрите, что он отправляет по сети в ваш PHP. Наконец, в PHP посмотрите всё, что пришло: `<?php print_r( $_POST);`